# Access custom ApplicationUser property from view in ASP.net Core 2

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I extended the `ApplicationUser` class to have 2 extra properties, `FirstName` and `LastName`. Both properties are persisted correctly in the database.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I am following a simple beginner example, and the code in question is as generated by the New Project with User Authentication command:

```
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager

@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <form asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout" method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="Index" title="Manage">Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link">Log out</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
}
```

And instead of `Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!` I would like to say `Hello ???????.FirstName!`

I cannot find a way to access those extra properties from the view. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to inject a [UserManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn468199(v=vs.108).aspx) into your service (or view in your case). This has a generic type parameter which in your case would be `ApplicationUser`:

```
UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;
```

You can then query users via the [UserManager.Users](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt151669(v=vs.108).aspx) property.
Alternatively if you need to get the current user and have their `ClaimsPrincipal` you can use the following code to retrieve the corresponding `ApplicationUser`:

```
ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(claimsPrincipal);
string firstName = user.FirstName;
```

Although I (personally) am not so keen on it, .Net Core supports [injection into views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/dependency-injection) using the following syntax.

```
@inject UserManager<ApplicstionUser> UserManager
```

Comment: I see that I already have a User injected, which is of type `ClaimsPrincipal`. How would a query for the user attributes would look like?

Comment: @HMihail: I have updated my answer with regards to using `ClaimsPrincipal`. Can you please update your question with your code?

Comment: @HMihail You can just use `Hello @UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result?.FirstName` although it might be nicer to get the ApplicationUser first and assign to a variable.

Comment: I love you @CalC.  So easy...wading through documentation for hours to get the above line of code.

Comment: Glad it helped @infocyde ☺️